# In jqgrid, how can I load data by condition?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

```
$("#list").jqGrid({
        url: "assets/PHP/userManager/user-read.php",
        datatype: "json",
        mtype: "GET",
        colNames: ["UserId", u, "User_Group_Id"],
        colModel: [
            { name: "UserId", hidden: true },
            { name: "UserName", width: 270, align: 'center', stype: 'text' },
            { name: "User_Group_Id", hidden: true}
        ],
        height: "87%",
        pager: "#pager",
        rowNum: 30,
        sortname: "UserId",
        sortorder: "asc",
        viewrecords: true,
        gridview: true,
        autoencode: true,
        multiselect: true,
        caption: "User List"
    }); 

    $(".ui-jqgrid-titlebar").hide();
    $("#pager_right").hide();
    $("#pager_center").width(220);
    $(".ui-pg-input").height(13);

    $("#list").navGrid( "#pager", {
        search: true,
        add: false,
        edit: false,
        del: false,
        refresh:true,
        searchoptions: {left: '30%'}
    });

    $("#search_list").click(function(){
        $("#searchmodfbox_list").css( "left", "30%" );
    });
```

This is the jqgrid I'm using in my code, and I create some buttons. I need a method or event from jqgrid that I can click the button and call that method, then it will load data with all data contain a pattern.

For example, I have a button called "student", when I click that it will filter all the data which the role field is student, so the grid will show me all the students.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. After the jqgrid is completely loaded, I can use this to set a parameter for the grid and trigger the reload to refresh the grid. But it has a problem that the parameter is always 'groupId=1', then the search or filter won't work properly. To fix this problem, I have to set the postData to nothing.

```
$("#list").setGridParam({'postData' : 'groupId=1'});
$("#list").trigger("reloadGrid");
$("#list").setGridParam({'postData' : {}});
```